# JavaFX is not reading imports that are necessary

Tags: java, fxml, javafx-11

I am learning javafx and am currently working on how to use two stages. I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cS6JsmECDcU) but when I made my new fxml file, it shows that the java imports are unused. I can't move forward with my program without it.

This is how it should look like in my IDE.
[Working Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgu5R.png)

But this is how it looks like when I built a new fxml file.
[Unused Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXGlw.png)

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/